# index of 3rd smallest element in max heap

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, heapsort

How do i find the possible indices of 3rd smallest element in max heap of 1 to n distinct elements?
I know that the smallest element will anywhere in the leaf. 
the second smallest will be anywhere from n/2 to n for n greater than 3
But i dont not know to to calculate for 3rd smallest. Any suggestions?

Comment: In a true [binary max-heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), the smallest (n+1)/2 nodes will be leaves if I recall my data structures correctly. Your third smallest value will therefore be one of those nodes or an immediate parent of one of those nodes. I cannot fathom a closed-form algorithm capable of extracting that value in O(1) time, even assuming the heap is already completely built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third-smallest element has at most two descendants, which means that its child(ren) are leaves, or it is a leaf. (To prove this, you also have to prove that it is impossible for an element with only one child to have a non-leaf as the child. Easy but tedious.)

Leaves, as you almost note, have indices in the range `[floor(n/2)+1, n]`. If `n/2` is an integer, then that element has exactly one child (which is a leaf), so adding that gives the range of indices which might contain the second-largest element.

An element whose first child is in the leaf range `[floor(n/2)+1,n]` has at most two children, and no non-leaf child. That range is contiguous with the [ceil(n/2),n] range, and the union of the two ranges provides all the possible positions for the third-largest element.

The first child of the element at `i` has index `2i`, so the first element whose first child is at least `floor(n/2)+1` is `floor(n/4)+1`.

Thus, the possible indices at which you could find the third-largest element is the range: `[floor(n/4)+1,n]`.

---

Here's another approach. Take some element at index `i`. Its immediate children are `2i` and `2i+1`; its grandchildren are `4i, 4i+1, 4i+2, 4i+3` and, in general, it's descendants at level `k` are `2ki, 2ki+1, ..., 2ki + 2ki-1`; in summary, `[2ki, ..., 2k(i+1)-1 ]`. These ranges are, of course, non-overlapping (indeed, unless `i` is `1`, they're not even contiguous). So if `i` has at least one descendant at level `k`, it also has a complete set of descendants for all `k' < k`, of which there are `2k-2`.

From all of that, we can conclude:

- If `n ≥ 2ki and n < 2k(i+1)`, then `i` has:

  - `2ki-2` descendants at some level less than `k`
  - `n - 2ki+1` descendants at level `k`;
  - Total: `n-1` descendants.
- If `n ≥ 2k(i+1) and n < 2k+1i`, then `i` has:

  - exactly `2k+1-1` descendants.

Roughly speaking, this means that the last `2k` elements are not found in the first `1/2k` part of the heap's underlying array.

Comment: I too got the same solution...came to the final conclusion that the formula for the indices for the i(th) smallest elements will be [n/(2^(i-1))] to n. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: It's more like "the indices for the 2^i(th) smallest elements". See edit. (Not complete, but you can probably complete it yourself if I don't get back to it in time.)